# Speed up Excel UDF

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I have a basic UDF that concatenates the multiple matches for a vlookup basically

```
            Function MYVLOOKUP(lookupval, lookuprange As Range, indexcol1 As Long, indexcol2 As Long, indexcol3 As Long)
            'disable slow apps
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

            'main code
            Dim r As Range
            Dim result As String
            'set string to null instead of nothing
            result = vbNullString
            For Each r In lookuprange
                If r = lookupval Then
                    result = result & " " & r.Offset(0, indexcol1 - 1) & " " & r.Offset(0, indexcol2 - 1) & " " & r.Offset(0, indexcol3 - 1) & "|"
                End If
            Next r
            'output results
            MYVLOOKUP = result

            'enable apps
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

            'end function
            End Function
```

Is there any way to speed this up, my boss does not want to add any new data or columns to the spreadsheet so it has to be this function. But running this on over 320000 cells takes a long time.

All help is appreciated.

UPDATE: added some speeding up code, but still slow

Data is formatted in this way

```
     Sheet 1
    1 |   |
    2 |   |
    3 |   |
    4 |   |
    5 |   |
    6 |   |
    7 |   |
    Sheet 2
    1   |1a     |b      |c
    1   |1ab    |bb     |cc
    1   |1abc   |bbb    |cccc
    1   |abcd   |bbbb   |cccc
    2   |a      |b      |c
    2   |ab     |bb     |cc
    2   |abc    |bbb    |cccc
    2   |abcd   |bbbb   |cccc
    3   |a      |b      |c
    3   |ab     |bb     |cc
    4   |a      |b      |c
    5   |a      |b      |c
    6   |a      |b      |c
    7   |wer    |werr   |rewsfd

    i need it to look like this
    1 |1a b c| 1ab bb cc| 1abc bbb cccc| abcd bbbb cccc|
```

it has to be able to handle 20 columns

Comment: Instead of having a `function` that takes one cell and returns one value, try adapting it so that it's a `sub` that takes 32000 cells in one go and returns an array of 32000 cells once it's done

Comment: I'm not positive but turning screen updating off might make it run faster.  Try placing `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end.

Comment: Instead of a for Loop, Use Find() or WorksheetFunction.Match() to find the row in which the lookup value is found then use that with the columns to return the desired values.

Comment: As above but also add `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning then `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end.

Comment: Since you want to optimize a working function, I suggest you post on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This puts the range into an array before looking for the value.  You can add any number of columns to the return as long as they're within the range of the lookup table.

I haven't tested it on a big recordset, but surely an array will be faster?

```
Public Function MYVLOOKUP(LookUpValue As String, LookUpTable As Range, ParamArray lColumn()) As Variant

    Dim vTable As Variant
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim lMaxCol As Long
    Dim sResult As Variant

    vTable = LookUpTable

    'Check a column outside the range of LookUpTable isn't being asked for.
    For x = LBound(lColumn) To UBound(lColumn)
        If lColumn(x) > lMaxCol Then
            lMaxCol = lColumn(x)
        End If
    Next x

    If lMaxCol <= LookUpTable.Columns.Count Then
        'Work through the array looking for the value, and return values from specified array elements.
        For x = LBound(vTable, 1) To UBound(vTable, 1)
            If vTable(x, 1) = LookUpValue Then
                For y = LBound(lColumn) To UBound(lColumn)
                    sResult = sResult & " " & vTable(x, lColumn(y))
                Next y
            End If
        Next x
    Else
        'Column outside the range is asked for - return a #REF error.
        sResult = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    End If

    MYVLOOKUP = sResult

End Function
```

**Edit:** Wondering if I could do the whole lot in one hit using an array formula and `Application.Caller`

Comment: this is a great choice, for some reason i pass it =MyVlookup(A2,!Sheet2!A:N,3,4,14) and it wont run?

Comment: `=MyVlookup(A2,!Sheet2!A:N,3,4,14)` You've got a `!` before Sheet2 as well as after it.

Answer (score 0):

You are running it over 320000 cells..okay. How many times are you running it?  Is it a calculated column and you have 320K formulas in it or do you just have 10 or 20 formula?   Please update your answer with screenshots of sample data, and a sample of the actual formula and I will improve my answer.

It makes a big different if `LookUpTable` is a single column or multiple columns.  I `LookUpTable` is a single column then don't use an UDT.  Using a combination of `Match` and `Index` is probably your best bet.

You should read: [EXCEL VLOOKUP VS INDEX MATCH VS SQL VS VBA](http://analystcave.com/excel-vlookup-vs-index-match-vs-sql-performance/).

Exiting the function after a match is found will greatly improve performance.

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(LookUpValue As String, LookUpTable As Range, Column1 As Long, Column2 As Long, Column3 As Long) As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xResult As String
    xResult = ""
    For Each rng In LookUpTable
        If rng = LookUpValue Then
            MYVLOOKUP = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, Column1 - 1) & " " & rng.Offset(0, Column2 - 1) & " " & rng.Offset(0, Column3 - 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: I'd say OP's wouldn't exit after first match but keep on looping and concatenate the result of all matches. And, you're right, he/she should state the columns size of `LookUpTable`

Answer (score 0):

you could use an `AutoFilter()` approach:

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(LookUpValue As String, LookUpTable As Range, Column1 As Long, Column2 As Long, Column3 As Long) As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim refCol As Long
    Dim xResult As String

    With LookUpTable '<--| reference table
        refCol = .Columns(1).Column '<--| assume referenced table 1st column as column to offset "result" columns from
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=LookUpValue '<--| filter on referenced table 1st column with given 'LookUpValue '
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell filtered other than header (which is in first row)
            For Each rng In .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| loop through table 1st column filtered not empty cells after headers row
                xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, Column1 - refCol) & " " & rng.Offset(0, Column2 - refCol) & " " & rng.Offset(0, Column3 - refCol)
            Next rng
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    MYVLOOKUP = xResult
End Function
```

assuming:

- `LookUpTable` may be any multi-column range
- `LookUpTable` first row are "headers"
- `Column1` , `Column2` , `Column3`, are absolute column indexes where to grab "result" cells from

  they may even be outside `LookUpTable` columns range

Answer (score 0):

Matt, is this what you are looking for?

```
Sub TableFromRelational()
Dim InArr: InArr = Selection.CurrentRegion.Value
Dim Coll As Scripting.Dictionary
Set Coll = New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim RsltArr
Dim I As Long
For I = LBound(InArr) To UBound(InArr)
Dim Key As Double: Key = InArr(I, LBound(InArr, 2))
If Coll.Exists(Key) Then
RsltArr = Coll(Key)
ReDim Preserve RsltArr(UBound(RsltArr) + 1)
Coll.Remove Key
Else
ReDim RsltArr(0)
End If
RsltArr(UBound(RsltArr)) = InArr(I, LBound(InArr, 2) + 1)
Coll.Add Key, RsltArr
Next I
Dim DestRng As Range
With Selection.CurrentRegion
Set DestRng = .Offset(0, .Columns.Count + 1).Cells(1, 1)
End With
DestRng.Resize(Coll.Count, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Coll.Keys)
For I = 0 To Coll.Count - 1
RsltArr = Coll(Coll.Keys(I))
DestRng.Offset(I, 1).Resize(1, UBound(RsltArr) + 1).Value = RsltArr
Next I
End Sub
```